# Hiding mutual recursive functions in SML

Tags: sml

I have two functions that rely on each other heavily. Each one must use the other one in order to perform the desired task.

I used the `and` operator in SML when I used them.

The problem is that I am required to hide every single function that is not the main one. I was taught to use `local` in order to perform this but I never reached this situation, I can't understand how something like this will work syntax wise.

I am referring to something like this:

```
local
  f()
in
 g()
end;
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third "main" function to start things off – your local `f` can't be mutually recursive with `g`.

Like this:

```
local
    fun f x = something with g
    and g x = something with f
in 
    fun h x = whatever
end
```